# I am using Node.js and the Facebook API, I have problem in this function and I don't know how to resolve it

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, facebook-graph-api, async-await

[When creating an e-commerce chat bot, I want to search the information related to a user cart (products in his cart) and send this information as a list to messenger.

I wrote a function like in the link below and when testing i got this error without returning any element in messenger.

Failed calling Send API 400 Bad Request {
message: '(#194) param name_placeholder[elements] has too few elements.',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 194,
fbtrace_id: 'AWTjz9pQlZ_kfwU-GHjq-mB'
}

I think the problem is that the call to the function that send the message is executed before searching for information about each item and appending MyArray.

How can I resolve that problem and what's wrong with the function][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7SxV.png)

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted. Do not just show images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if you replace the **forEach** loop with a **for...of** you will get your desired results.

```
for await (const item of items) {
  // do your async stuff
}
```

A forEach will iterate over all the items and execute the provided callback for each element, but it will not wait for promises or respect the async/await.
It expects the callback to be synchronous:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

So at the time you use the MyArray it will be empty - the promises returned from the forEach callback will not be resolved.

*Also, it's better to always include the code  in your question as mentioned in the above comment.